# Facebook FB.Event.subscribe "bug" with the edge.create callback

Tags: facebook, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

Im fancing a really weird problem with the edge.create callback.

What im doing is to execute an ajax call to the server each time an edge.create or edge.remove event occurs (the firs is to like and the second to unlike a page).

Heres the code

```
        // this will fire when any of the like widgets are "liked" by the user
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
                var dataSend = 'ajaxFace=true&submitAdd=true&code='+SomeCodeToAdd;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://somewebpage.com',
                    data: dataSend,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    erro: function(data) {
                        alert('Try again later');
                    }
                });
            });

            //this will fire when any widgets are "disliked" by the user
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget){
                var dataSend = 'ajaxFace=true&submitDelete=true&code='+SomeCodeToRemove;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://somewebpage.com',
                    data: dataSend,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    erro: function(data) {
                        alert('Try again later');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Now, whats happening.

The function for the 'edge.remove' event works smooth and without any problems.

But when the user click **like** the code simply dont run on the success part of the ajax call, i tryed a simple alert like alert('test'); but nothing happens  too. The code, however, works fine on the backend and the code I want to add is added with success.

However if i set the async : false the code works, the alerts is presented on the page but the browser gets that nasty "lock down" that i really want to avoid.

So, anyone have any idea whats exactly going on here?

PS.: Theres 2 others facebook elements on this page, the comments and activity feed. I dont know but im with the impression that the activity feed may have something to do with this...

Comment: I know you probably have it right on your side, but you have `erro` as a parameter in the JSON elements than `error`.  Maybe your getting an error and not realizing it?  (Unless you  have a stack overflow translation issue, which everytime i ask a question, i mess up on translating my code to stack overflow :))

Comment: Ohh have you tried this.   `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) { alert(href); });` to verify that FB is recognizing your subscribing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is some sort of scope issue.  If you define the function containing the ajax call outside of the scope of the FB.Event.subscribe, and just call that function from within the FB.Event.subscribe,  that may fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
HI i was facing the same problem but for different FB event. Here is my code an it 100% working :-

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Facebook Like Button</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>--->(DO not forget to include)
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '464134126954048', status: true, cookie: true,xfbml: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe("message.send", function(targetUrl) {
     $.ajax({
        url:'abc.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{name:'sunlove'},
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert("I am here");
        }
     });      
    });

  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<fb:send href="http://demo.antiersolutions.com/studybooster1.2"></fb:send>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"> </script> 

</body>
</html>
You can just copy and make new file and customize according to your need
```