# Workaround for Facebook edge.create being removed from the api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

We have a credits system than rewards people for liking  us on facebook, for marketing purposes. 
If they like us via the button we put on our platform, we offer them a credit.

We used to implement this by listening to the event edge.create

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '....',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
       function(response) {
         //give credit
       }
    );
```

Recently this stopped working  since edge.create was take out of the events that you can subscribe to, based on the answer to this question:
[Facebook like callback event using edge.create is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042404/facebook-like-callback-event-using-edge-create-is-not-working)

adn this blog psot:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/?locale=en_US

Is there a work around for this? I would prefer some JS solution.
Webhooks seems complicated and i not sure it would even works since i don't know how i would identify which facebook user is the user in our system (they can have  different emails, names etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have a credits system than rewards people for liking us on facebook

Like gating or rewarding people for liking a Page is not allowed since many years - and now not possible anymore. There is no workaround.

This would be the specific part of the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

> Don’t incentivize people to like a Page, or give the impression that
>   liking a Page will be rewarded

Comment: And to add. The way the OP did it yes recently stopped working. But it haven't been allowed for many many years if ever.

Comment: yeah, i´ve added that information just in case, thanx :)

Comment: did not know about the policy but it makes sense. Thanks